# How prevent a user from accessing a client side html file with express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am writing a "todolist" application. In my node.js code I make use of express and give it access to my folder called **Client**:

```
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/Client"));
```

In my **Client** folder is the following:

```
codeJS.js
homepage.html
Todolistpage.html
style.css
logo.jpg
```

How can I prevent a user to not be able to view my **Todolistpage.html** file when they type in **localhost:3000/Todolistpage.html** (without removing **Todolistpage.html** from my **Client** folder)?

(Ideally later on I try to only allow users logged in to view it)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier if you don't serve the file statically and handle it as part of the view logic. So you would just remove it from the public directory and handle it separately with `app.get()` or `router.get()` middleware. Is there a reason why you need to serve it statically?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var app = express();

app.get('/Todolistpage.html, function(req, res) {
  return res.status(401).end();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Client');
```

This isn't ideal as you'll have to change it anytime the file name changes, and have to do it individually for each file.

You could also have a different directory `/secure` and some middleware for user auth like:

```
app.use('/secure', someAuth, express.static(__dirname + '/secure'));
```

or even...

```
app.use('/secure', someAuth, express.static(__dirname + '/Client/secure'));
```

but that seems confusing to me.